# Approving/Rejecting edit suggestion reinitiates snippet

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, stack-snippets

Looks like the snippet is reinitiated for the second time after approving or rejecting an edit suggestion that uses the snippet.

**Example 1:**

[image]

**Example 2:**

[image]